# Passing entity framework results to a method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have a method `CreateTreeView()` that I call in order to turn a flat, self-referential table into a tree view as below.

```
   ID   |   DisplayName  |  ParentID  |
--------|----------------|------------|
    1   |   Top Level    |    NULL    |
    2   |   Sub Level    |      1     |
    3   |   Sub Level 2  |      2     |
    4   |   Top Level 2  |    NULL    |

public static void CreateTreeView()
{
    using(var Context = new MyDBContext())
    {
        foreach(Department dept in Context.Departments.Where(d => d.IsVisible == true)
        {
            // Create the tree recursively
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

```
-- TopLevel
        |---Sub Level
            |--- Sub Level 2
-- TopLevel2
```

This works perfectly and outputs a JSON string that's picked up by jsTree in the front-end.

What I'm struggling with, is that there may be times when I need to create a treeview from different tables. In my example above, I'm querying the Department table. However, I would like to generalize my `CreateTreeView()` method to accept the results of an entity framework query and generate a tree based on that.

Using the old ADO.NET approach, I would have stuffed results into a `SqlDataReader` and passed them across and worked with that. However, as I'm new to Entity Framework I'm struggling with getting my head around passing the results to the method, as I could technically be passing any query results to this, so how do I derive the object types etc.

Ideally I'd imagine something like this (**property names in the results are passed as parameters to the method**)

```
public static void CreateTreeView(var results, string DataValueField, string ParentIDField, string DataTextField){

    foreach(**UnknownObject** Result in results)
    {
        // Create the tree recursively
    }
}
```

I've tried defining the results parameter in the method as `IQueryable` etc, but as I said above, I don't know the type of the entity that I'll be passing in.

I've thought about creating method overloads for different entity types, but I'm not sure if that's the way I need to go with this? It feels like I'd be duplicating code, and that makes me sad..

I'm just looking for a pointer in the right direction really, I spent a couple of hours last night searching for things, but I guess I've not been searching very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use some generics. One approach could be this:

```
public static void CreateTreeView<TEntity, TValue>(IEnumerable<TEntity> results, Func<TEntity, TValue> dataField, Func<TEntity, int> parentField, Func<TEntity, string> dataTextField) {
    foreach (TEntity result in results) {
        var value = dataField(result);
        var text = dataTextField(result);
        int parentId = parentField(result);
            // build your tree rerursively
    }
}
```

Here you have a set of your results and some functions which return value, text and parent id respectively for given entity type. Usage is:

```
using(var Context = new MyDBContext())
{
    var tree = CreateTreeView(Context.Departments.Where(d => d.IsVisible == true), c => c.DataField, c => c.ParentID, c => c.TextField);
}
```

Another approach might be to define an interface for your entities:

```
interface ITreeEntity<T> {
    T Value {get;}
    string TextField {get;}
    int ParentID {get;}
}
```

And allow building trees of entities that implement that interface. Then you don't need to pass functions to get values explicitly.

Comment: This is perfect! I've implemented it using the generic method you specified and now I'm refactoring to use the Interface! Thanks for helping me understand this :)